# PHP cannot create directory even though parent folder is 777

Tags: php, permissions

I understand the security implications of 777. This is just a troubleshooting measure.

Parent folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx.  3 web   www-data    22 Jun  5 11:04 library
```

For good measure the immediate parent is also 777.

PHP is running as apache:

```
print shell_exec( 'whoami' );
```

Returns `apache` which is a member of the `www-data` group:

```
# groups apache
apache : apache www-data
```

The `mkdir` command fails:

```
mkdir("/var/www/html/library/temp__9pa2spj13nkiatknv8odqrv3n0");
```

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/html/test.php

If I try to `chdir` to the directory first, I can `getcwd()` and it's correct. If I try to create the directory at that point if fails.

I'm out of ideas on what to test.

Here's my entire test script for good measure:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
print shell_exec( 'whoami' );
mkdir("/var/www/html/library/temp__9pa2spj13nkiatknv8odqrv3n0");
chdir("/var/www/html/library");
echo getcwd();
mkdir("temp__9pa2spj13nkiatknv8odqrv3n0");
```

Comment: See where it says `drwxrwxrwx.` with a dot at the end?  I suspect that means there are ACLs.  What operating system is the server running on? Do you have a shell command `lsacl`?  If you do, what does `lsacl /var/www/html/library` print?

Comment: No lsacl command.  CentOS Linux 7 (Core). CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7, Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-123.20.1.el7.x86_64

Comment: Please explain the downvote.  Is the question not clear? Is it not detailed?  I searched for some time and didn't see any duplicates for this situation. Is there some sort of secret phrase I forgot to utter?  Is this your way of telling me I'm stupid?

Comment: What are the permissions for /var, /var/www, /var/www/html ... ?

Comment: var is root/root 775. /var/www is root/www-data and is 775, html is web/www-data and is 775.

Comment: Generally I set permissions to be even more restrictive.  I set var to root/root 755, /var/www to root/www-data 775

Comment: I'm not familiar with SELinux ACLs, but I get this when I do ls --lcontext:  drwxrwxrwx.  3 unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 web   www-data    22 Jun  5 11:04 library

Comment: If you've got SELinux active (and enforcing), the bad news is the permission bits are effectively irrelevant, but the good news is there should be clues in /var/log/auth to what's really wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SE Linux should be configured to block writes to any files by the web server (Apache). The `httpd_sys_content_t` shows that the directory is set to read only. You need to set it to read/write by using the `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` context. This can be done using the `semanage` tool. The command would look like this.

```
semanage fcontext -a httpd_sys_rw_content_t "/var/www/html/library(/.*)?"
```

After you set that policy, you can apply it by doing...

```
restorecon -Rv /var/www/
```

Comment: Thanks - I'll test this tonight, and if it works I'll accept the answer.